# Is there a better way to specify url and method when the controller doesn't match the model in Rails 3.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, model, tags

In Rails 3.0 I have a TagsController which handles a model that is not called Tag, but ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag, which means that urls are generated wrong: acts_as_taggable_on_tag_url instead of tag_url.

That forced me to write this abomination as the form:

```
form_for @tag, :as => :tag, :url => @tag.new_record? ? tags_url : tag_url(@tag), :html => {:method => @tag.new_record? ? :post : :put}  do |form|
    ...
```

Is there a better way to do it? Somehow telling Rails that the controller for that module is named differently?

I know I could separate that in two different files, but I'd rather not.

Comment: What version of rails are you using? Rails 2.x or 3.x?

Answer (score 0):

I think It doesn't make any difference that you are using ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag model instead of Tag. @tag class will matter only. If @tag is having ID then Update otherwise create.
Try with the general syntax of form_for.

Comment: from_for uses @tag's class to make the urls; @tag's class is ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag, not tag, thus the broken URLs. I've already tried (before asking).

Comment: Try with redirect option of routes.